# hive job failed on java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, hive, tez

```
hive>  select distinct symbol from minute_bars;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = root_20160317130023_bb1b06c0-0d81-4c0b-bf52-eced43c68818
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1457381948140_0016, Tracking URL = http://xxxxxxdb02:8088/proxy/application_1457381948140_0016/
Kill Command = /opt/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1457381948140_0016
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2016-03-17 13:00:32,440 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1457381948140_0016 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

--- hive.log

```
2016-03-17T13:00:32,531 ERROR [d30a1694-2e56-4256-91b5-2c10e59051ad d30a1694-2e56-4256-91b5-2c10e59051ad main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(1016)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

--- job log from hadoop

```
User:   root
Name:   select distinct symbol from minute_bars(Stage-1)
Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
Application Tags:   
State:  FAILED
FinalStatus:    FAILED
Started:    17-Mar-2016 13:00:29
Elapsed:    2sec
Tracking URL:   History
Diagnostics:    
Application application_1457381948140_0016 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1457381948140_0016_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://******db02:8088/proxy/application_1457381948140_0016/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hive/root/d30a1694-2e56-4256-91b5-2c10e59051ad/hive_2016-03-17_13-00-23_424_1080910785670801632-1/-mr-10005/76e0c5f4-e2ba-4880-843d-5ce62fad9463/map.xml does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Please help check what is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: can you also provide the AM logs if possible for both or one attempts ?

Comment: I am totally new to hadoop. not sure what is AM log. I got some information from yarn-root-nodemanager-hostname.log

Comment: core-site.xml <configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://dnjdbamongo02:9000</value>
</property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/${user.name}</value>
    </property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
 </property>

Comment: hive-site.xml part of the definition   <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/opt/hivescratchdir</value>
    <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user,
an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/&lt;username&gt; is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.</description>
  </property>